# Google maps MarkerClusterer and spiderify integration

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to google maps API. We already have a developed google maps API integration with markerclusterer and all the nodes are clustered. But the problem is with the nodes with same coordinates. They are overlapping and only the first node is visible.

I have gone through many threads with OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier solution. But the problem i'm facing is that i'm not able to integrate the same with existing code.

In current code we are actually looping through data and creating markers for the same with markerhtml as the marker message and then calling a function which inturn calls the addlistener method for click function which takes marker and markerhtml as input and setcontent into infoWindow. At last we add the marker into the markers array.

My explanation about the problem may not be appropriate as i'm new to this and learning. Can anyone please guide me with steps of integrating existing markerclusterer with spiderify.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/markerclusterer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/oms.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/microajax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/splitter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.corner.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/map.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link href="main.css" charset="UTF-8" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
    <link href="map.css" charset="UTF-8" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
.style2 {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.style4 {
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.hide{
visibility: hidden
}

</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
</script>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: white;">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

map.js

```
// Show the overlay layered and popup div
  function showPopup(id) {
    var overlaypopup = document.getElementById('dialog-overlay');
    overlaypopup.style.display = 'block';
    var popup = document.getElementById(id);
    popup.style.display = 'block';
  }

  // Hide the overlay layered and popup div
  function hidePopup(id) {
    var overlaypopup = document.getElementById('dialog-overlay');
    overlaypopup.style.display = 'none';
    var popup = document.getElementById(id);
    popup.style.display = 'none';
  }


// Inventory file Path and inventory names variables
            var INVENTORY_FILE_PATH = '<inventory_Data>'
            var INVENTORY_TYPE_AB = 'AB';
            var INVENTORY_TYPE_MF = 'MF';
            var INVENTORY_TYPE_PF = 'PF';

            var RED_STATUS =2;
            var BLUE_STATUS =1;
            var GREEN_STATUS =0;

            // Default google map init variables
            var MAP_INIT_LAT =  22;
            var MAP_INIT_LNG =  80;
            var MAP_INIT_ZOOM = 4;
            //var MAP_INIT_MAX_ZOOM = 16;

            // Marker Cluster init params
            var MAX_MAP_CLUSTER_ZOOM = 13;
            var MAX_MAP_CLUSTER_GRIDSIZE = 50;

            // Link to icons for inventory
            var BLUE = './images/blue_oneLinkDown.png';
            var RED = './images/red_siteDown.png';
            var GREEN = './images/green_allLinkUp.png'; 


            var MARKER_INFO_WINDOW_WIDTH = 50;
            var MARKER_INFO_WINDOW_HEIGHT = 50;

            var REFRESH_TIME = 10000 * 1500;

            var markerSearch;  //
            var map;
            var oms;
            var markers = [];
            var filterMarker = [];
            //var markerWindowHtmls = [];

            var markerCluster = null;
            var mcOptions = {gridSize: MAX_MAP_CLUSTER_GRIDSIZE, maxZoom: MAX_MAP_CLUSTER_ZOOM};

            var searchedMarker;
            var idleMapZoomListener;

            // Bounds for United Kingdom
            var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                new google.maps.LatLng(8.13, 77.42),
                new google.maps.LatLng(33.04, 76.79)

            );
            // Marker information window
            var markerInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                    { content: '',
                      size: new google.maps.Size( MARKER_INFO_WINDOW_WIDTH, MARKER_INFO_WINDOW_HEIGHT)
                    });



            // Initilize and load the google map when page is loaded
            function initialize() {

                var center = new google.maps.LatLng(MAP_INIT_LAT,MAP_INIT_LNG);

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: MAP_INIT_ZOOM,
                    //maxZoom: MAP_INIT_MAX_ZOOM,
                    center: center,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });

                alert("TEST");
                // Create OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier instsance
                oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);     
                alert(oms);

                microAjax(INVENTORY_FILE_PATH, processMarkers );

                // Listen for the dragend event
                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {

                    if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) {
                    return;
                    }



                    // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

                    var c = map.getCenter(),
                    x = c.lng(),
                    y = c.lat(),
                    maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
                    maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
                    minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
                    minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

                     if (x < minX) x = minX;
                     if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
                     if (y < minY) y = minY;
                     if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

                     map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));

                });



                // This is necessary to make the Spiderfy work
                  oms.addListener('click', function(marker) 
                  {
                    markerInfowindow.setContent(marker.desc);
                    markerInfowindow.open(map, marker);
                  });   

            }


            function attachMarkerMessage(marker, message) {
                alert("Inside attachMarkerMessage");
                /*google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    markerInfowindow.setContent(message);
                    markerInfowindow.open(map,marker);
                    });*/

            }

            // Reads the inventory file and creates all Marker for each item.
            processMarkers = function (markerdoc) {

            lines = markerdoc.split("\n");

                var lat;
                var lng;
                var marker;
                var markerHtml;
                var markerLatLng;
                var lineSplit = [];
                var currMarkerIcon;
                var option;
                var searchMarkerSelect = document.getElementById("markerSearchSelect");



                for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                  if ( lines[i].length > 1) {
                     lineSplit = lines[i].split(",");

                        if ( lineSplit.length  == 16 ) {
                            lat = parseFloat(lineSplit[12]);
                            lng  = parseFloat(lineSplit[13]);

                                     if (lat != 'NaN' & lng != 'NaN') 
                                    {

                                        if (lineSplit[14] == GREEN_STATUS)  {

                                                currMarkerIcon = GREEN;
                                        }
                                        else if (lineSplit[14] == RED_STATUS)
                                        {
                                            currMarkerIcon = RED;
                                        }
                                        else if (lineSplit[14] == BLUE_STATUS)
                                        {
                                            currMarkerIcon = BLUE;
                                        }



                                        markerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( parseFloat(lineSplit[12]), parseFloat(lineSplit[13]) );
                                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                            position: markerLatLng,
                                            title: lineSplit[1],
                                            optimized: false,
                                            icon: currMarkerIcon
                                        });



                                        marker.set('LOCATION', lineSplit[0].trim());



                                        markerHtml = '<span style=\'font-family: Arial;font-size:12px;\'>LOCATION: <b>' + lineSplit[0]+'</span>';

                                        marker.desc = markerHtml;
                                        alert(marker.desc);
                                        //attachMarkerMessage (marker, markerHtml);
                                        oms.addMarker(marker);
                                        alert(oms);
                                        markers.push(marker);
                                    }
                        }
                    }
                }



                if ( markerCluster == null ) {
                    markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, filterMarker, {imagePath: 'images/m', maxZoom: 15});

                } else {
                    markerCluster.clearMarkers();
                    markerCluster.addMarkers(filterMarker, false);
                    //markerCluster.redraw();
                }

            }


            function showMarkerInfo(index){

                hidePopup('popup');


                idleMapZoomListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
                         google.maps.event.trigger(filterMarker[index], "click");

                         google.maps.event.removeListener(idleMapZoomListener);
                    });


                if (map.getZoom() == 16 ) {
                    map.setZoom(17);
                } else {
                    map.setZoom(16);
                }

            }




            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

its not able to create instance
oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);

Uncaught ReferenceError: OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier is not defined

Comment: related question: [Overlapping Pointers with MarkerClustererPlus and OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569748/overlapping-pointers-with-markerclustererplus-and-overlappingmarkerspiderfier)

Comment: I have gone through almost all the threads. I have facing issue with below code var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map,{markersWontMove: true, markersWontHide: true}); I have added this in initialize function. I have creating a new instance of OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier after map and i have also included oms.min.js and markerclusterer.js. But the problem the code is getting stuck at OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier instance creation.

Comment: There is no indication of your specific issue in your question.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Please find below part of code where i'm facing issue:<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/markerclusterer.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/oms.min.js"></script>

Comment: function initialize() {
     
     var center = new google.maps.LatLng(MAP_INIT_LAT,MAP_INIT_LNG);
     
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: MAP_INIT_ZOOM,
      //maxZoom: MAP_INIT_MAX_ZOOM,
      center: center,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });

     
     // Create OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier instsance
     oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map,{markersWontMove: true, markersWontHide: true}); )\n\n its not initializing OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier instance

Comment: markerclusterer is working perfectly. But trying to implement above code to resolve issue for same coordinates.

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments (it isn't readable). Update your question with the [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: hello, please find code updated in question

Comment: Doesn't seem very minimal; please remove all the extraneous code to leave a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a working code snippet that demonstrates the issue would be ideal)

Comment: I have already removed extra code. This code just contains clustering part with  overlappingmarkerspiderify integrated. Can u please confirm what should be the version of Google maps api.